# How to redirect to another route in a JS class in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have done a class to manage all the things about json web tokens, and it works until I updated all packages. Now I get the following error:

```
React Hook "useHistory" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

And here is the code of the class:

```js
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

class ClassJWT {
  constructor() {
    this.axiosJWT = axios.create();
    this.history = useHistory();
  }

  async refreshToken() {
    await this.axiosJWT.post("http://localhost:3001/refresh-token", {
        token: sessionStorage.getItem("refreshToken"),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.statusCode !== "200") {
          this.history.push("/signin");
        } else {
          sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.newAccessToken);
          sessionStorage.setItem("refreshToken", res.data.newRefreshToken);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  async checkJWT() {
    let currentDate = new Date();

    const decodedToken = await jwt_decode(
      sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
    );

    if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < currentDate.getTime()) {
      await this.refreshToken();
    }
  }

  getToken() {
    return sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
  }
}

export default ClassJWT;
```

The thing is that I need to redirect in this class (because the user has to login if the token is incorrect or he doesn't have any token), but the thing I have done is incorrect.

So, anyone know how can I do this in a correct way that works??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, React hooks are incompatible with class-components. You can create a custom history object (to be passed to router of your choice) that you can then import and use in other classes/code used by your app.

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router)

Example:

1. Create and export browser history object

   ```
   import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

   export const history = createBrowserHistory();
   ```
2. Import history object for router

   ```
   import { Router } from "react-router";
   import { history } from "../path/to/history";

   ReactDOM.render(
     <Router history={history}>
       <App />
     </Router>,
     node
   );
   ```
3. Import history object for `ClassJWT`

   ```
   import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
   import axios from "axios";
   import { history } from "../path/to/history";

   class ClassJWT {
     constructor() {
       this.axiosJWT = axios.create();
       this.history = history;
     }

     async refreshToken() {
       await this.axiosJWT.post("http://localhost:3001/refresh-token", {
           token: sessionStorage.getItem("refreshToken"),
         })
         .then((res) => {
           if (res.data.statusCode !== "200") {
             this.history.push("/signin");
           } else {
             sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.newAccessToken);
             sessionStorage.setItem("refreshToken", res.data.newRefreshToken);
           }
         })
         .catch((err) => console.log(err));
     }

     ...
   }

   export default ClassJWT;
   ```

If you use a `HashRouter` then import `Router` and use [`createHashHistory`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/packages/history/index.ts#L616), for `MemoryRouter` use [`createMemoryHistory`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/packages/history/index.ts#L882), etc...

Alternatively you could convert `ClassJWT` into a React class-component and decorate with the [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component. This will inject the `history` object into props from the closest `Router` component in the React tree.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import axios from "axios";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class ClassJWT extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); // <-- don't forget to call super!
    this.axiosJWT = axios.create();
  }

  async refreshToken() {
    await this.axiosJWT.post("http://localhost:3001/refresh-token", {
        token: sessionStorage.getItem("refreshToken"),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.data.statusCode !== "200") {
          this.props.history.push("/signin"); // <-- access from props
        } else {
          sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", res.data.newAccessToken);
          sessionStorage.setItem("refreshToken", res.data.newRefreshToken);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default ClassJWT;
```

Or you can do the above ***and*** convert it to a React function component so you can use the `useHistory` hook.